# Doesn't Firefox work at full speed when it's not the default browser?

Tags: firefox, browser

Today I saw the following text on my Firefox.

> Make Firefox your default browser and browse at full speed. Visit Firefox → Preferences → General in your dropdown menu. Click "Make Default".

So Firefox doesn't work at its full speed when it isn't the default browser?

[image: Make Firefox your default browser and browse at full speed. Visit Firefox → Preferences → General in your dropdown menu. Click "Make Default".]

Comment: Wow. Very odd. But why are you tagging this as “Google-Chrome?” What OS are you on?

Comment: It’s kind of like Microsoft suggesting you make Edge your default browser so you can have the fastest and most secure experience. If Firefox isn’t your default then clearly something else is. Therefore, you can’t possibly be going as fast as Firefox will make you go. If you believe that.

Comment: If its the default it will load faster as you won't need to explicitly select it when opening html files/links

Comment: Ironically, it was already selected as the default browser.